# Pass array to awk which contains the column numbers which need to be printed

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, awk

I have a CSV file (**usvd.csv**) which contains 41 columns, my bash script process the headers row to workout which columns to print, the result is I need to print 26 of the 41 columns. These can differ - **The number of columns in the CSV and or the number of columns that need to be printed.**

The array the contains the number of columns that need to be printed is as follows:

```
${UNIQUE[@]} = 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 20 21 26 30 35 37 39 40 41
```

So out of the 41 columns I only want to print the columns listed above and they can differ from file to file.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cut`.  Consider the following example:

```
UNIQUE=(1 2 4 6)          # Array containing columns to be printed
fields=$( IFS=, echo "${UNIQUE[@]}")      # Get the fields in comma-delimited form
# seq -s, 10 would print the string: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
seq -s, 10 | cut -d, -f"${fields[@]}"     # Print the desired fields
```

This would results in

```
1,2,4,6
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does this print the related columns(The actual data) of the csv file?

Comment: Instead of `seq -s, 10` in the example above, say `cat filename` where filename is the name of your csv file.

Answer (score 6):

I like @devnull's solution, but just for completeness I will suggest an `awk` version:

```
$ list=$(echo "${UNIQUE[@]}")
$ awk -vd="$list" 'BEGIN{split(d, a, " ")} {for (i in a) printf "%s ", $(a[i]); printf "\n"}' file
col3 col4 col7 
col3 col4 col7 
col3 col4 col7
```

For a given file

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
```

#### Explanation

- `list=$(echo "${UNIQUE[@]}")` converts the array into a string with space separated fields.
- `-vd="$list"` passes the bash variable `$list` to awk to be used as `d`.
- `BEGIN{split(d, a, " ")}` splits the `d` string into pieces by space, so that a[1]=field1, a[2]=field2, ...
- `{for (i in a) printf "%s ", $(a[i]); printf "\n"}'` loops and prints.

Comment: Why not list="${UNIQUE[@]}"?